# I have a problem in connection with SQL Server port

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, express

I am trying to connect my project with SSMS. I get this error:

> Failed to connect to SQL Server: ConnectionError: Port for SQLEXPRESS not found in DESKTOP-RE32RAN
>
> [0]     at C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\fyp-main\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious\connection-pool.js:85:17
> [0]     at Connection.onConnect (C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\fyp-main\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:838:9)
> [0]     at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:628:26)
> [0]     at Connection.emit (node:events:513:28)
> [0]     at Connection.emit (C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\fyp-main\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:959:18)
> [0]     at C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\fyp-main\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:995:16
> [0]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
> [0]   code: 'EINSTLOOKUP',
> [0]   originalError: ConnectionError: Port for SQLEXPRESS not found in DESKTOP-RE32RAN
> [0]       at C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\fyp-main\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:995:32
> [0]       at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:77:11) {
> [0]     code: 'EINSTLOOKUP'
> [0]   }
> [0] }

I have enabled the SQL Server Browser but when I clicked on SQL Server Network Configuration to enable TCP/IP Port, there was nothing there.

Please help me with this problem.

[TCP/IP not there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE5E4.png)

This is the connection code:

```
const config = {
  host: "localhost",
  server: "DESKTOP-RE32RAN\\SQLEXPRESS", 
  database: "fyp", 
  options: {
    trustedConnection: true, 
  },
};

// SQL Server connection pool
const pool = new sql.ConnectionPool(config);
const poolConnect = pool.connect();
```

I have checked the server name and enabled the SQL Server browser. This the first time I am connecting Express/Node with SQL so I am a newbie in this one, previously I was managing data in MongoDB.

Comment: You need to click on network configuration there you see named pipes and tcpip

Comment: SQL Server hasn't had a 32 bit version for a long time now. Instead of looking in the "SQL Server Network Configuration (32bit)" node have you looked in the "SQL Server Network Configuration" node?